# How to show Occurences for Javascript in Aptana?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor, aptana

I am trying to show occurences when browsing .js files in Eclipse (just simple occurences like it does for C).

For example, if I highlight myVar, then Eclipse should show boxes in a ruler where other occurences of myVar occur in the file.

I've gone into Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations multiple times, de/selected and applied changes to Javascript Occurences, Occurences(com.aptana.ide.annotation.occurences), Occurences(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.occurences) all to no avail(C occurences continue working perfectly on .c files).

I've opened .js files in default Javascript editor and in Aptanas .js editor with no results.

Even really dumb show of occurences which would show any selected text(var, null, etc.) would be great.

Additional information on workspace: Eclipse 3.5(didn't work on 3.4 either), Ubuntu 9.04, CDT, Aptana, Subversive, and some other plugins. .js files are from a large non-web project.

Comment: Problem solved: Windows->Preferences->Aptana->Editors->check Mark Occurences with background color(pick ones favorite color)

I'll have to play around with JSEclipse and see how its editor works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To circumvent your problem, you could use the JSEclipse plug-in (http://www.interaktonline.com/Products/Eclipse/JSEclipse/Installation-Update/). It supports occurrence markers, code completion, etc.

Comment: Accepted, although there are other plugins available, your suggestion is a fine one.